# Started learning react and I am trying to build a simple image search using unsplash API but I am having trouble rendering to the page

Tags: reactjs

I have been working on this app for a few days now. I have got the API to log to console onClick but can't work out how I am suppose to render it onto the page. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const App = () => {   const AUTH = "##########";   const API_URL = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos?query=london&client_id=${AUTH}`;

  const [loadImages, setloadImages] = useState([{}]);
    async function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const response = await fetch(API_URL);
    const data = await response.json();
    setloadImages(data);
    console.log(data)   }
  
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form className="form">
        <div className="input-group mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Search Photos..."
            aria-label="Search Photos..."
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            Search
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul>
          {loadImages.map((image) => (
            <li>
              <img src={image.data} alt=" " />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>   ); };

export default App;
```

[Screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBvJ7.png)

Comment: What is the shape of the data you get from the fetch? Move the console.log before the setImagesData to make sure it is called.

Comment: The console.log before and after the setimagesData returns the same, an array of objects containing each image.

Comment: What is the shape of each image? 
Does it render anything at all or do you get an error?

Comment: oh sorry, its rendering bullet points with the image placeholder next to it, The one you'd get if it couldn't load an image.

Comment: You use the ```image.data``` for the src of the img tag. Are you sure the ```image.data``` is the property you want? 
I don't know the shape of the image object.

Comment: reading through the object i thought it should be image.urls but that returns the same as image.data

Comment: Can you update the question with the example output of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response from the api, the `data` property does not exist on the object. Instead, you should access one of the URLs. This snippet is using raw URL, but you might want to look at other ones

```
          {loadImages.map((image) => (
            <li>
              <img src={image.urls.raw} alt=" " />
            </li>
          ))}
```

**Edit**

To answer the comment that it throws an error that it cannot read property raw (or any other) of undefined, it is most likely because one of the objects does not have this property. In that case, you can do a conditional render to make sure it exists before rendering the image tag.

```
          {loadImages.map((image) => (
            <li>
              { image.urls && <img src={image.urls.raw} alt=" " /> }
            </li>
          ))}
```

Comment: That was actually what i tried originally, although i did {image.urls.regular} but it just throws an error of "cannot read property "regular" of undefined"

Comment: That has corrected the issue! I know you have already helped a lot but could you explain whats actually going off here? it is still looking for the same property so why does the {image.urls &&} fix the issue?

Comment: I'm glad it helped! So it is a conditional render. It checks if the left-hand side of the ```&&``` is true, and if it is, it renders the right-hand side. Otherwise, it skips rendering it. So if ```image.urls``` is undefined, it returns ```false``` in this condition, and the render is skipped and the ```image.urls.raw``` is never called and it does not cause issues. You can read a bit more about conditional renders here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html